# Entries from wrong channel in results page

Tags: low-search

I've got an issue where results from the wrong channel are showing up on the results page.

Some background on the site:

#### Channels

- pages_nl
- pages_fr
- pages_en
- vehicle_nl
- vehicle_fr
- vehicle_en

The search results tag looks like this:

```
{exp:low_search:results  
  collection="vehicles_{segment_1}|pages_{segment_1}"
    status="not closed"
    limit="10"
    disable="member_data"
 }
```

The results look like this:

- entry from **vehicle_nl**, entry_id is **1401**
- entry from **page_fr**, entry_id is **1390**
- entry from **page_nl**, entry_id is **1338**
- entry from **page_en**, entry_id is **1364**

So if I'm reading it correctly, entries 1390 and 1364 should not be in this list.
I've rebuilt all indexes, no joy.

The problem isn't specific to these entries, other queries that have a match in the 3 languages show up as well.

We use the same template/low_search:results tag for the results pages in the other languages and those are fine.

Any suggestions on how to debug this?

Comment: Is the site publicly accessible so we can see the URL that is causing issues? If not what is the URL that is causing problems compared to one that is working? Are you using a specific add-on for what I am assuming is a multi-lingual site?

Comment: Not using an add-on for the multi-lingual part, just lots of playa relations. Url isn't live yet so show you, looks like this: for nl => nl/zoekresultaten/?keywords=ariel, for en => en/search/?keywords=ariel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix it: some entries were in more then one collection in the exp_low_search_indexes table. Truncated those tables, rebuilt all indexes and the results were correct.